# How to get number of Facebook page likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

my following script doesn't show the number of fb-page-likes anymore...

```
$ch = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKPAGE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($raw);
$scm_fb = $data->likes;
echo $scm_fb;
```

I tried also the following code, but this also displays nothing...

```
$page_id = "FACEBOOKPAGE"; 
$likes = 0; //Initialize the count

//Construct a Facebook URL
$json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

//Extract the likes count from the JSON object
if($json_output->likes){
    $likes = $json_output->likes;
}
```

(I also tried the Facebook-Page-ID instead of the pagename, result is the same)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use graph api to get the details of the page with corresponding access tokens. If you already have a valid access token, please use the below code to get the page details.

```
$fb_page = ''; 
$access_token = '';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'?access_token='.$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);
$details = json_decode($result,true);
echo "Likes:".$details['likes'];
```

Comment: this returned a json with only "name" and "id".

Comment: Does not work anymore, they changed response even for old versions, nice.

Comment: New working url: `https://graph.facebook.com/[.....]?fields=fan_count&access_token=[.....]`

Answer (score 6):

You can get any graph object or url likes by parsing [Facebook Like Widget](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator) source code using this php snippet:

```
<?php

    $id = "youtubetabapp";
    // customize: "https://facebook.com/[customize]"    
    $url = "https://facebook.com/$id"; // by name
    //$url = "https://facebook.com/282374908483303"; // or by id

    // customize: "locale=[customize]&" to your needs
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/like.php?locale=$locale&href=".$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Safari');
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    //die( var_dump( $html ) ); // <- debug fetched data
    // have a look for the data you need and customize your regex pattern accordingly
    // "preg_match([customize], $html, $match);"
    preg_match("/([0-9,.]+[a-zA-Z,\S]) people like this./", $html, $match);
    $likes = $match[1];
    //$likes = str_replace(array(".", "K"), array("", "000"), $likes); // <- customize output | remove ".", replace "K" with "000"
    //$likes = (float)$likes; // <- customize output | change type to float, strips prepending non-digits (eg: "K") as well
    die( $likes );

?>
```

Compare to API methods you don't need to provide any tokens and it takes one single request. Based on my tests — you only need to keep `locale` parameter to make sure that you have constant source code for parsing.

Comment: This still works like a charme! Instead of saying "thx|+1|whatever" I enhanced your awesome answer. Hope you are happy with my edit. I tried to make it more debugable and enhanced your regex pattern to work in more scenarios. Should work with copy & paste now out of the box which wasn't the case before (at least not for me)...

Answer (score 3):

You can't get any page like without providing your access_token to the Facebook Graph API.

Your URL should be like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{YOUR_PAGE_ID}?fields=like&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

If you want to learn about how to use Graph API and how to generate your access_token try following links.

**FACEBOOK GRAPH API - Pages**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

**Access Token - Pagetoken**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

**GRAPH API EXPLORER**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=765898450131958%3Ffields%3Dlikes&version=v2.2&

Comment: Yes, just don't forget to add valid Access Token.

Comment: I've generated a valid token and changed the url like above, but the output is nothing. Are App ID and APP secret not necessary in the code?

Comment: App ID and App Secret key require to generate Access Token. I insist you to know more about Facebook PHP SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: Yes, I know, but are these necessary in the code too?